# how to send escape character in python json

Tags: python, json

I want to send a post request that contains the following data:

```
{"id":"12345asdf","tag":"\"8522e2de632040fc728440da7b23806a\""}
```

my post request looks like this:

```
data = {"id":f"12345asdf","tag":"\"8522e2de632040fc728440da7b23806a\""}
requests.post('site. com/splash', data=json.dumps(data))
```

here's what python sends in this case:

```
{'id': '12345asdf', 'tag': '"8522e2de632040fc728440da7b23806a"'}
```

How do I make sure that escape character

> \

are sent in the right places in json?

Comment: `{"tag": r'\"8522e2de632040fc728440da7b23806a\"'}`

Comment: The escape character says to treat the following character in a special way; for special characters, such as `"`, this means treat them as normal ones.  The escape character itself is a special character.  So...

Comment: Why are you trying to double-quote that hex string? Why not use `"8522e2de632040fc728440da7b23806a"` ?Python did what you told it to do - send a JSON string that actually starts and ends with double quotes.

Comment: If you're using the `requests` library... any particular reason to not use `requests.post(..., json=data)` directly?

Comment: If you really want those backslashes in the sent message double them `\\ `